# how to display a field that set as RAW

Tags: sql

the table structure set field  = RAW
such as:  `APPLICATIONGUID NOT NULL RAW(32)`
so when it displays, it is unreadable charcter: `[B@39982d`  = acc001

now I want to select that field with acc001
How do my select statement will be?

Answer (score 0):

Raw is for storing binary data, i believe, so you should know what is stored in there. It could be an image or an executable file, etc...

Comment: yes, i know text value in that field, but dont know how to pull them outwith select statement with ....select * from tablename where applicationguid='acc001';  i enter acc001 did not work b/c it looking for RAW data ????

Comment: If you are developing this database schema i would advise you to use another datatype to store your "applicationguid" data, such as varchar2, or char. These exist to store string data like you have in your example. Another way to go would be to write a function to convert your "raw" data to a text data type and use it in your query: select * from table(getVarcharFromRaw('acc001'));
Unfortunately i can't help you with that, as i am not really oracle savy.